# Packets getting dropped with Libpcap in C on 1 Gig Traffic

Tags: c, tcpdump, libpcap, packet-capture, tcpreplay

I'm writing a packets parser in C using libpcap library. Here is the simple code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pcap_t *pcap;
    const unsigned char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
    clock_t begin = clock();

    // Type your interface name here 
    
    char *device = "ens33";
    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_t *handle;
    int timeout_limit = 10000; // milliseconds

    if (device == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error finding device: %s\n", error_buffer);
        return 1;
    }

    // For live packet capturing
    handle = pcap_open_live(
        device,
        BUFSIZ,
        0,
        timeout_limit,
        error_buffer);

    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error getting handle%s\n", error_buffer);
        return 2;
    }

    pcap_loop(handle, 0, dump_UDP_packet, NULL);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


    printf("Program completed: total packets processed: %d (non UDP/Radius packets: %d) in %f seconds\n", count, non_packets, time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using tcpreplay to play live traffic from a pcap file. My program however is only able to process / read around 80,000 packets from a file of 240,000 packets. When I try to read the same packets from tcpdump, I get no packet loss.

Is this due to buffer size? How can I ensure packets are not lost ?

The tcpreplay takes around 1.5 to 2 seconds at high speed (~500MB/sec)

I'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04 (32 GB RAM, 24 core processor)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files,  Are you expecting use to guess what header files you actually used?

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding; `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  This causes the compiler to output 2 warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`   `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned char *packet;`  How can that pointer be `const` when it does not point to anything?

Comment: regarding; `if (device == NULL)`  This will never be true due to: `char *device = "ens33";`

Comment: you might want to read [pcap example](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section3.html)

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to read the same packets from tcpdump, I get no packet loss.
>
> Is this due to buffer size?

Unless you use the `-B` command-line option, tcpdump does not set the kernel buffer size (which you're also not doing, as you're using `pcap_open_live()`, which doesn't have a way to set it; the snapshot length is *not* the buffer size), so it's using the same default buffer size (2 MiB) that your program is using, so it's probably not the buffer size.

> How can I ensure packets are not lost ?

Try using tcpdump's timeout of 1 second (1000 milliseconds) rather than 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds), which is what you're currently using.

Also, make sure `dump_UDP_packet()` isn't doing too much work (you haven't provided the source to let us know what it's doing).

> I'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04 (32 GB RAM, 24 core processor)

And both your program and tcpdump are using one core.  (After a context switch, they may run on a core different from the one on which they were running before the context switch, but it's still one core at a time; neither of them are multi-threaded, unless there's some threading in the part of your application that you didn't show.)